# How to set Default Profile Spring

Tags: spring, spring-profiles

Here's my scenario:

```
a.xml
-----
<beans> <!-- no 'profile' attribute -->
    <bean id="a" class="com.a.A"/>
</beans>

b.xml
-----
<beans > <!-- no 'profile' attribute -->
    <bean id="b" class="com.b.B"/>
</beans>

c.xml
-----
<beans ><!-- no 'profile' attribute -->
    <bean id="c" class="com.c.C"/>
</beans>

<beans profile="dev">  
    <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory"
    host="x.x.net" username="a" port="xxxx"
    password="a" />

    ....
    ....

</beans>
```

**Objective**:

1. When I run my app in local, I want to load all beans from a.xml, b.xml and all beans from C.xml except profile "dev"
2. When I run my app in dev environment, I want to load all beans from a.xml, b.xml and all beans from C.xml

I am setting -Dspring.profiles.active=!dev as a JVM System Parameter. Issue is it's not loading the other beans.

Any idea, how do I handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be behaving as you expect without any profiles at all passed in during local (pending you are importing all 3 xml files). The beans element with "dev" will only get loaded when spring is started with the dev profile.

Comment: Thanks, @LetsBeFrank. 1. it's loading all the beans from a,b,c.xml except for the one which is marked as "dev" in Local if I don't pass any profile. 2. It's loading all the beans from a,b,c.xml including the bean which is marked as "dev" when I pass : -Dspring.profiles.active=dev,default